# php variable equality comparison short way

Tags: php, if-statement, comparison

i have a statement in my php:

```
<? if(isset($_GET['mod']) && ($_GET['mod'] == "category" || $_GET['mod'] == "catalog")) echo 'id="active"'; ?>
```

i want to learn how to write this types of double comparison in the second part (after &&) like this:

```
<? if(isset($_GET['mod']) && $_GET['mod'] == ("category" || "catalog")) echo 'id="active"';?>
```

but it's not working.

there are many pretty if-one-liners in php that i often use in my websites and i wonder to learn one more ))

Comment: Stop using short php tags please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it like:

```
if( isset($_GET['mod']) && in_array( $_GET['mod'], array( "category", "catalog") )
```

As @RepWhoringPeeHaa suggested, stop using short tags as some of the server might not support them.

Also as suggested below, you should try to separate the PHP code outside of the html, like so:

```
<?php

    $active = '';

    $mods = array( "category", "catalog" );
    if ( isset( $_GET['mod'] ) && in_array( $_GET['mod'], $mods ) ){
       $active = 'id="active"';
    }

?>

// html
<div <?php echo $active; ?>></div>
```

Comment: thanks, it's a little shorter. yes short tags are bad, will reduce the usage of them. thanks !

Comment: <?php if(isset($_GET['mod']) && in_array($_GET['mod'], array("catalog","category"))) echo 'id="active"';?>   ---  this works for me, thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php 
if(isset($_GET['mod']) && in_array($_GET['mod'], array("category", "catalog"))) {
    echo 'id="active"';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First: stop using short php tags. Use: `<?php`. Because when you are using the short syntax you are depending on some server setting to be enabled (which is a bad thing).

If you want to make your code better readable and maintainable you could do something like:

```
<?php

$values = array('category',
                'catalog',
               );

if(isset($_GET['mod']) && in_array($_GET['mod'], $values)) {
    echo 'id="active"';
}
```

This way it it way better readable and way better maintainable. If you want to check for another value you only have to add an item to the array and it will keep working.

Remember it's not writing the shortest code that's important it's the best maintainable code that matters.

Comment: this is totally undesirable for short, inline PHP logic in HTML templates. i need short, one-line insertion of PHP code right into a HTML template to make it look accurate. but thanks for in_array() ))

Comment: No it isn't. Again as I stated you shouldn't make everything into one short line. That sucks for other people (as well as yourself) to maintain the code and see what is going on.

Comment: what you wanna do is keep logic outside of the html template altogether, e.g. do `$active = 'id="active"';` outside of the html code and then just do `echo $active;` in place ... that way you keep both php and html readale

Comment: @scibuff +1 to that, but it sounds OP it looking for the wrong way.

Answer (score 0):

The second comprasion type should not work , because the syntax is wrong. You cannot "attach" two objects and then compare them to another object in if statement.

Answer (score 0):

PHP 5.4 supports short tags by default, regardless of the ini configuration.

Also, if this isn't code likely to be distributed to other servers, it is safe to use short tags, though, if you were to change server that doesn't support short tags you'll be in trouble.

Answer (score -2):

you can use array or if you dont want you must do it :

```
if(isset($_GET['mod'])  AND  (($_GET['mod'] == "category" ) OR  ($_GET['mod'] == "catalog"))) echo 'id="active"';
```

Comment: there is many way to do that , it's one way and you know , and for better case if you want your code structure is readable and good you must use AND , OR Instead && , ||